# Classification of drone imagery (RGB) with SCP

Tags: qgis, classification, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, rgb, scp

How can I work on the classification in orthophotos (generated by Metashape from a DJI Phantom drone) when I cannot input the orthopoto into the band set? SCP does not find the raster of the orthopohoto in the single band list.
I know SCP cannot use orthophotos with less than 4 bands.  Is there a way to go with SCP or do I need to use a different method?

I'm totally new in QGIS and especially, in classification.

I want to classify the water, sediment and oyster reefs in the Wadden Sea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to split the orthophoto into 4 rasters with each a band and use them to create the ROI polygons.

Open SCP --> Click on 'Split Raster Bands' --> Select your orthophoto in Multiband Raster --> You get 4 new rasters to work on.